# How can I test Debug (Cpu & FPS) usage on hybrid apps build by Phonegap & Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, cpu, phonegap

I have been looking for a very long time over 6 months how to debug & test the Cpu/Fps of hybrid apps build by PhoneGap & Cordova

I have an Apple Paid Developers Account (99$), I can install the Apps on the iPhones with the Development Provisioning profile but the problem I cannot find a way to test this Apps (Cpu & Fps) so I can  fully debug and make proper arrangements to improve performance before sending it to the App store, it is very difficult to develop apps on this Darkness not knowing how much Cpu is costing me this mechanics on the Game or that mechanics etc.... is like working blindness, this is one of the Topics that no one talks about it or at last I couldn't find References while I was looking, which is surprising as is one of the most important aspects of developing a Game, I feel like I'm missing something here. 
Can any of you guys please point me on the Right Direction as I'm tired looking and I can't find the answer 
I just need something that will allow me to test real (Cpu/Fps) usage once the App is installed on the iPhones That's all

As an example Why is important for me:
One of the Mechanics on my Game is a Pathfinder and this, as you know, is quite heavy Cpu so I did hundreds of different ways or setups for this Pathfinder but the problem I cannot choose which one is the best for the job if I cannot test the Cpu/Fps usage for this mechanics.
And the same thing Happens with the other heavy-duty Mechanics.
I can't believe that doesn't exist Tools for ios to debug these things or at list is not easy to find them.
Thanks very much for reading

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official Apple documentation on Performance Tools:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html

If you need to open the Cordova app in Xcode, you can do the following.

Step 1. Ensure app is built, run this command in your Cordova projects folder:

```
cordova build ios
```

Step 2, open Xcode

Step 3, open a project and search for the Xcode Project File in your project's sub-folder:

> <project-folder>/platforms/ios/

Comment: Thank you so much @Christopher Bull I was looking at the wrong places then as I was looking for windows I don't have a Mac, I checked the Link and it looks quite impressive the so many tools they have on Xcode,

Comment: I borrowed a Mac just to test the Xcode but I didn't manage to open my project following your steps, an important note I'm not a coder I use just a (No code engine) to make the Games and then after I use PhoneGap to build the Ipa file, I can't find the Place to enter your code, this is the project file before I upload to PhoneGap if you dont mind to have a look :  [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqsnnco9losebv7/C2.zip?dl=0)